# Is it possible to hide installed application from other applications?

Tags: android

Is it possible to hide somehow your app package from the list returned by `context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0)`
or `context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities`
or from the checks using `context.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)`?

I heard about the problem when companies do not allow to use their apps in the case of detecting installed one from the concurrent company. They probably use one of these checks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want that? And no, I haven't ever met an app that isn't exposed by one way or the other to packages. This is how apps find out what apps are on your phone. And so far, even without root, those apps have found all the packages installed.

Comment: @AhmadSattout I heard about the problem that the app of one company is detected in such way by the big concurrent. So it became interesting for me is there possible way to handle this

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to hide installed application from other applications?

Not on a conventional Android device.

With root, this might be possible, but it might mean that the app is useless (if nothing knows the app is there, nothing will cause the app to run).

> I heard about the problem when companies do not allow to install their apps in the case of detecting installed one from the concurrent company.

That too is not possible. Until the company's app is installed, it has no means of determining what other apps are installed. An app might refuse to *run* based on conditions like what other apps are installed, but it cannot prevent *its own installation* based on such conditions.

Comment: App just shows the dialog that it will not proceed to the next screen until the uninstall of the app developed by a concurrent company. Thanks for your response.